# Отправка формы разбитой на две части

Tags: modx

Доброго времени суток, друзья! У меня к вам такой вопрос: будет ли работать отправка формы если разбить ее на два блока, один из которых будет скрытым, а другой видимым? Делаю примерно так:

```
<form class="form-horizontal ms2_form" id="msOrder" method="post">
<div class="shipping-form">
...тут поля всякие input'ы...
...и ссылка сокрывающая див shipping-form и показывающая pay-form...
</div>
<div class="pay-form" style="display:none;">
...тут еще input'ы и кнопка субмит...
...и ссылка сокрывающая див pay-form и показывающая shipping-form...
</div>
</form>
```

Скрипт на jquery делает то, что когда щелкаешь по ссылкам, то видимость дивов сменяется, один становится видимым, другой невидимым. Когда делаю отправку формы (щелкаю на субмит), то отправка не срабатывает. Вопрос почему? Из-за того что часть input находятся на скрытом div или из-за чего-то другого? Работаю на Modx Revolution, оформляю все это дело в своем чанке. Кто знает как решить эту проблему?

Comment: @IntegralAL, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.

Answer (score 1):

При сабмите должно отправляться всё, что находится внутри тэга `<form>`, так что ищите ошибку в том как отправляется. Может просто formit установить забыли. В общем слишком мало информации чтобы сказать точней, но отправляться должно точно.